# Firebase can't find databaseURL when separate databases are made using process.env

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, webpack, firebase-realtime-database

I wanted to have separate databases; one for testing and one for development and production. So using process.env variables and a little library called node-env-file i put the firebase config variables as process.env variables. But i get this error:

```
> Uncaught Error: FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Can't determine Firebase
> Database URL.  Be sure to include databaseURL option when calling
> firebase.intializeApp().
```

In webpack.config file:

```
        var envFile = require('node-env-file');

        process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

        try {
          envFile(path.join(__dirname, 'config/' + process.env.NODE_ENV + '.env'));
        } catch (e) {

        } 

    // (...)

     plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          'process.env': {
            NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
            API_KEY: JSON.stringify(process.env.API_KEY),
            AUTH_DOMAIN: JSON.stringify(process.env.AUTH_DOMAIN),
            DATABASE_URL: JSON.stringify(process.env.DATABASE_URL),
            STORAGE_BUCKET: JSON.stringify(process.env.STORAGE_BUCKET),
            MESSAGING_SENDER_ID: JSON.stringify(process.env.MESSAGING_SENDER_ID)

          }
        })
      ],

// (...)
```

In `config/test.env` and in `config/development.env` (those 2 files are similar, but of course the data is different):

```
API_KEY=myapikeyhere
AUTH_DOMAIN=myauthdomainhere
DATABASE_URL=mydatabaseurlhere
STORAGE_BUCKET=mystoragebuckethere
MESSAGING_SENDER_ID=memessagingsenderidhere
```

In `firebase/index.js`:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

try {
  var config = {
    apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.AUTH_DOMAIN,
    databaseURL: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    storageBucket: process.env.STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.MESSAGING_SENDER_ID
  };

  firebase.initializeApp(config);
} catch (e) {

}

export var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref();
export default firebase;
```

I updated firebase and the node-env-file libraries.

Answer (score 0):

In the firebase/index.js file, try

```
console.log("NODE_ENV",process.env.NODE_ENV) 
console.log("API_KEY",process.env.APP_KEY)
```

If API_KEY result is undefined,

- Make sure the config/ folder is in the right location.
- Remove any spaces in the .env files

If console.log shows the API_KEY, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

In your webpack.config.js replace reading .env file with the following

```
envFile(path.join(__dirname, 'config/' + process.env.NODE_ENV.trim() + '.env'));
```

So you'll get a trimmed string.

I had the same problem and when I printed the error in try/catch block I saw that envFile tries to find .env file like 'config/test. env'. The whitespace after the dot broke the code.
It appeared because of the whitespace here, I guess (between "test" and "&&") -> "NODE_ENV=test && karma start".

Realy tricky case.